# Design Library TabLayout, tab indicator bouncing after scroll

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-design-library

**EDIT The latest design libraries fixed this issue**

[compile 'com.android.support:design:+'](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)

I am working with the **TabLayout** in two instances, PagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter. In both cases the tab indicator bounces, when swiped between pages. The tab indicator doesn't bounce when clicking tab's to change pages.

I am not sure if it is an error on my part, it is a known issue, or part of the guidelines. If you need more code, or the other example I will post it.

**FragmentStatePagerAdapter**

```
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            LogMeal log = mLogMealAdapter.getItem(position);
            return MealViewFragment.newInstance(log.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) { // Tab text
            LogMeal logMeal1 = mLogMealAdapter.getItem(position);
            String s;
            if (logMeal1.getMealName().toString().trim().length() > 12) {
                s = logMeal1.getMealName().substring(0, 12) + "..";
            } else {
                s = logMeal1.getMealName();
            }
            return s;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLogMealAdapter.getCount();
        }
    });

    tabs.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#80ffffff"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    if (mLogMealAdapter.getCount() == 1) {
        tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    } else {
        tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    }
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_meal_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_meal_view"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently.
My workaround:

1) Change `tabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);` for

```
    \\ use own OnPageChangeListener 
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new MyPageScrollListener(mTabLayout));  

    \\ Manually add tabs, for example:  
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(mViewPager.getAdapter().getPageTitle(0)));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(mViewPager.getAdapter().getPageTitle(1)));  

    \\ use own OnTabSelectedListener  
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new MyOnTabSelectedListener());
```

2) Add implementation for custom listeners

```
 private class MyPageScrollListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    public MyPageScrollListener(TabLayout tabLayout) {
        this.mTabLayout = tabLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if(mTabLayout != null) {
            mTabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
}

private class MyOnTabSelectedListener implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        int position = tab.getPosition();
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != position) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Sorry, for not getting back to you.  I will test it out now and get back to you!

Comment: Thanks and sorry for not getting back sooner.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug on design support library 22.2.0

Maybe it will be fixed.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175073

Answer (score 1):

The indicator "*bouncing*" bug has been **fixed in version** **22.2.1** and superior.

Just update your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    //...
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}
```